# SSRS subquery based on other query

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services

I'd like to make an overview of projects.
This contains some fixed info; table projects joined with some other tables.
Now the report needs to have some subqueries: how many sales per salesman, how many is in transit, inventory, ... and so on.

I have a tablix with grouping on project (as to create an excel with one worksheet per projet).

How would I go about executing a new subquery per project (f.e. *select owner, sum(totalprice) from opportunities where project=xxx group by owner*)
I know I could achieve this with subreports; but as I will have about 10 subreports, I was hoping I could solve this with extra datasets and some filtering (and thus keep all logic in one file).

What's the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

I would create a dataset with this query:

```
select owner, project, sum(totalprice) as totalprice from opportunities group by owner, project
```

Next, in your tablix where you want to display owner and totalprice info, you will have an expression like this:

```
=LOOKUP(Fields!<FirstDataSetProjectFieldName>.Value, Fields!project.Value, Fields!owner.Value, "<NewDatasetName>")
```

The above code will send the value of the project you are searching for, match it with a the same field in your new dataset, then return the requested value from the new dataset. You can obviously do this for totalprice as well.

Check out the documentation for LOOKUP to get a better handle on it but I think this is the solution you are looking for.